# AdviceAdapter onMethodExit never called

Tags: java-bytecode-asm

I'm attempting to instrument a cassandra driver and in particular need to modify a ResultSet class to hang on to some information.  In order to do this I need to modify the code where the instance is being allocated, which is a static method in another class.  The code has this snippet in it:

```
return r.metadata.pagingState == null
    ? new SinglePage(columnDefs, tokenFactory, protocolVersion, columnDefs.codecRegistry, r.data, info)
    : new MultiPage(columnDefs, tokenFactory, protocolVersion, columnDefs.codecRegistry, r.data, info, r.metadata.pagingState, session);
```

It also has other returns within the method.  So my thought was to use an AdviceAdapter on this method and use the onMethodExit().  However, my method was never called.  That seems absurd since.. the method has to be returning!  After a little debugging, I find the visitInsn() in the AdviceAdapter class is being called just once, with an opcode of IALOAD (load an int from an array?).

I guess my question is.. what the hell is going on?  Heh.. sorry, bonked my head on my desk a few too many times today.

EDIT: I changed my class to be a simple MethodVisitor just to see if could see more opcodes, and indeed I do!  I see it all!  I just no longer have access to dup().  :(

Comment: If all you want is `dup()`, you only need a `GeneratorAdapter`, though I don’t get what’s so fancy about a short-hand for a simple `visitInsn(Opcodes.DUP)`. You can still let your custom visitor wrap a `GeneratorAdapter` or even an `AdviceAdapter`. It’s still hard to believe that everything stops working when your visitor is a subtype of `AdviceAdapter`, as there is no special casing in ASM regarding this type. Maybe you have overridden some other method in a way that disturbs it?

Comment: Hi Holger.  I tried a GeneratorAdapter and it too only saw that first OpCode.  I haven't overridden any other methods at this point, nor am I applying any other visitors to this class.  It's all quite odd.  Maybe eclipse is getting in the way somehow?  I'll try running my tests from the command line, see if anything acts better.

Answer (score 0):

I have used an EmailAdviceAdaptor (for **javax/mail/Transport**)  in one of my project, Code is given below. Hope this code will help to resolve your issue.

```
package com.mail.agent.adapter;

import com.mail.jtm.BTMConstants;
import com.mail.org.objectweb.asm.Label;
import com.mail.org.objectweb.asm.MethodVisitor;
import com.mail.org.objectweb.asm.Opcodes;
import com.mail.org.objectweb.asm.Type;
import com.mail.org.objectweb.asm.commons.AdviceAdapter;

public class MyEmailAdviceAdapter extends AdviceAdapter  {

private String methodName;
private String className;
private String description;

private static final String MAIL_SEND_METHOD1_DESC="(Ljavax/mail/Message;)V";
private static final String MAIL_SEND_METHOD2_DESC="(Ljavax/mail/Message;[Ljavax/mail/Address;)V";
private static final String MAIL_SENDMESSAGE_METHOD_DESC="(Ljavax/mail/Message;[Ljavax/mail/Address;)V"; 

private boolean isSendMethod;

private int okFlag =  newLocal(Type.BOOLEAN_TYPE); 
Label startFinally = new Label();

public MyEmailAdviceAdapter(int access , MethodVisitor mv , String methodName, String description, String className, int classFileVersion){
    super(Opcodes.ASM5 , mv, access, methodName, description);
    this.className = className;
    this.methodName = methodName;
    this.description = description;
    this.isSendMethod = false;

    if(methodName.equals("send")){
        if( description.equals(MAIL_SEND_METHOD1_DESC) || description.equals(MAIL_SEND_METHOD2_DESC)){
            isSendMethod = true;
        }
    }
    else if(methodName.equals("sendMessage") && description.equals(MAIL_SENDMESSAGE_METHOD_DESC)){
        isSendMethod = true;
    }
}

public void visitCode() {
    super.visitCode(); 
    mv.visitLabel(startFinally);
}

protected void onMethodEnter(){
    if(isSendMethod) {
        mv.visitInsn(Opcodes.ICONST_0);
        mv.visitVarInsn(ISTORE, okFlag);

        mv.visitVarInsn(Opcodes.ALOAD, 0);
        mv.visitLdcInsn(className);
        mv.visitLdcInsn(methodName);
        mv.visitLdcInsn(description);
        mv.visitMethodInsn(Opcodes.INVOKESTATIC, "com/mail/agent/trace/MailTracer", "mailMethodBegin", "(Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)Z"; , false);
        mv.visitVarInsn(ISTORE, okFlag);
    }
}

protected void onMethodExit(int opcode){
    if(opcode!=ATHROW) {
        onFinally(opcode);
    }
}

public void visitMaxs(int maxStack, int maxLocals){
    Label endFinally = new Label();
    mv.visitTryCatchBlock(startFinally, endFinally, endFinally, null);
    mv.visitLabel(endFinally);
    onFinally(ATHROW);
    mv.visitInsn(ATHROW);
    mv.visitMaxs(maxStack, maxLocals);
}

private void onFinally(int opcode){
    if(isSendMethod){
        // If the method throws any exception
        if(opcode == ATHROW){
            mv.visitInsn(Opcodes.DUP);
            mv.visitLdcInsn(className);
            mv.visitLdcInsn(methodName);
            mv.visitLdcInsn(description);
            mv.visitVarInsn(ILOAD, okFlag);
            mv.visitMethodInsn(Opcodes.INVOKESTATIC, "com/mail/agent/trace/MailTracer", "recordException", "(Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Z)V", false);
        }
        mv.visitLdcInsn(className);
        mv.visitLdcInsn(methodName);
        mv.visitLdcInsn(description);
        mv.visitVarInsn(ILOAD, okFlag);
        mv.visitLdcInsn(opcode);
        mv.visitMethodInsn(Opcodes.INVOKESTATIC, "com/mail/agent/trace/MailTracer", "mailMethodEnd", "(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;ZI)V", false);
    }
 }
```

}